# Trigonometric Substitution Method to solve Cubic Equation.

Tags: trigonometry, roots, cubics

Here are the questions.  IN the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Trigonometric_.28and_hyperbolic.29_method) page, it says p has to be smaller than 0. 
But they didnt really explain why...

Therefore, I assume it is impossible to have a complex number inside arcosine, is this the reason? arcosine( x + yi) --- is it possible?

Comment: You have to be a bit more specific. Where is the wiki page? what is $p$? and what have to do with cubic equation?

Comment: Sorry, i just added a hyperlink. p and q are components of a depressed cubic equation and the discriminant of the equation is 4p^3 +27q^2.

Comment: Not exactly *impossible*, more like inconvenient. If $p\gt 0$, then one can do something similar using hyperbolic functions.

Comment: they choose $u=2\sqrt{\frac{-p}{3}}$ this makes only sense if $p<0$

Comment: But for cubic roots they can be complex, so it will also make sense it u is complex thus produce complex solutions.